# What are $\cos(4 \tan(x))$ and $\sin(4 \tan(x))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to simplify the following two equations.

$\cos(4 \tan(x))$

$\sin(4 \tan(x))$

I tried to use both duplication and parametric formulas but I obtain many computations that give me some "strange" numbers. Can you help me please?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha doesn't find any further simplifications. What were you hoping? Also, they are "expressions", not "equations", as they aren't set equal to something.

Comment: This might be a really dumb question, but have you used the equality tan(x)=sin(x)/cos(x)?

Comment: You can use double-angle formulas for $\cos$ and $\sin$ to get expressions in terms of $\cos(\tan(x))$ and $\sin(\tan(x))$.

Comment: By the way, is there any chance that your original question didn't use $\tan^{-1}$ - that is to say  $\arctan$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael And what about $\cos(\tan(x))$?

Comment: Textbooks are expensive, but some should just be burned, and the ashes dissolved in acid. They should teach their students, not confuse or distract them. Trigonometric functions as arguments of trigonometric functions are rare, because they rarely make sense. Yes, _of course_ there are exceptions, like the integral representation of a Bessel function $J_n(x)= \frac1{\pi}\int^\pi_0\cos(n\theta-x\sin\theta)\,d\theta$, but... is there any evidence that the author of that "exercise" knew that?

Comment: There is basically nothing you can do to "simplify" $\cos(\tan(x))$.